# Every irreducible representation is either even or odd.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, linear-groups

Let $V$ be any $n$-dimensional complex vector space and $SL(2,\Bbb{Z})$ is special linear group. Let $\rho:SL(2,\Bbb{Z}) \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation. It is even if $\rho(-I)=\Bbb{id}_V$ and odd if $\rho(-I)=\Bbb{-id}_V$. Then show that any irreducible representation is either even or odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Use Schur's lemma to see that $p(I)$ and $p(-I)$ must act by scalars.
2. Note that $p(-I)^2 = p((-I)^2)) = p(I)$.

Comment: i know about the hints 2. (the homomorphisms gives this) but i donot know how to use Schur,s lemma and what do you mean by "act by scalars".

Comment: @YasirMahsud It means that $p(-I)$ is of the form $\lambda I$, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Hence, acting like a scalar. And Schur's lemma says that any endomorphism of an irreducible representation, a linear map commuting with the action of the group, is a scalar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma